# Improving my question about the Teachers' Lounge so it can be reopened

Tags: discussion, meta, specific-question, off-topic, reopen-closed

I am trying to improve my Meta Stack Exchange question [Rename the Teachers' Lounge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336927/336163) in order to get it reopened. It was closed in October 2019 for the reason "**This question does not appear to be about the software that powers the Stack Exchange network, within the scope defined in the help center.**". I'm not quite sure why the Teachers' Lounge is off-topic, as it is a notable feature of the network and the tag ([teachers-lounge](/questions/tagged/teachers-lounge)) has many well-received questions.

To be clear, I am aware that the change I proposed was somewhat controversial (+22/-40 as of the posting of this question), and I accept the downvotes. What I'm trying to do is figure out what I need to do to get it reopened so that others can add their perspectives.

What can I do to bring the question on-topic for Meta Stack Exchange so that it can be reopened?

Comment: You think everything would go back to being OK if this happened? Perhaps it's seen as a wallpapering question?

Comment: @RobertLongson no, where did I say that? My concern is why even proposing such a change was deemed off-topic.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that if you propose rearranging the deck chairs, not everyone will be in favour that that's a suitable topic when they think there are more important things to discuss.

Comment: @RobertLongson perhaps, but that is normally a reason to downvote, not vote to close.

Comment: Indeed. I voted to leave it open so perhaps one of the close voters will see this and chime in.

Comment: It was closed by five users, not closed by a single mod. If users think.the question should be reopened, they will cast their votes. It doesn't look to be a question of priority. Sorry.

Answer (score 10):

It's also well ... frankly a strange case if sticking your nose into something you wouldn't see and isn't likely meaningful change. Renaming the chatroom wouldn't have reduced the tension in any way.

Fundamentally - what's the change you hope to see from this? How is it a matter of policy or direction that would impact the network or moderator community as a whole?

Comment: This isn't what I'm asking. I'm not asking how to make my proposal into a popular one. I'm asking how to make it *on-topic*. Feature requests are not off-topic just because they are unpopular. For example, the feature request [Add “undecided” to the up vote/down vote system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253183/336163) was much more poorly-received than mine (+2/-52) yet has never been closed as off-topic.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Different times. The band was playing, the iceberg was nowhere in sight and the ship was unsinkable

Comment: Just because the question is invalid doesn't mean that it's a blatantly off-topic question.

Comment: @RobertColumbia, I don't think you can make your proposal on-topic. It would be on-topic (at a guess, but not being a moderator I don't know specifics for what is on topic) on the moderator Team site, as it's the chat room for moderators. What is it that makes you think that the broader community should have a say in the name of the chatroom that moderators use?

Comment: Having the chatroom named differently certainly wouldn't have reduced the tension. But single-handedly re-closing this question instead of just leaving it reach its own doom isn't going to have any beneficial effect to the tension either.

Comment: Well depends on the tension. I have heard many complaints over many things but never the name. And it does seem very opinion based what the name should be, especially with no real investment in the chatroom in question

Answer (score 9):

People seem to be voting to close as off-topic to express strong disagreement (I can't see how it's actually off-topic).  I don't feel this is the intended use of close votes.

Anyway, I cast the 5-th reopen vote so it's reopened (at least, for now).

Comment: There have also been documented cases of people using *delete* votes for the same purpose - for disagreement - almost all of which have been dealt with by moderators, some even by deleting and undeleting to clear out votes. Don't see why the same thing shouldn't be done with close votes.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think the question is meaningful for non-moderator users.

And if user-moderators want to discuss this, I think they already have a Teams instance devoted to mod-related Q&A.

Wouldn't that be the appropriate place to post a question like this?

Answer (score 4):

Posted as a comment 10 hours ago… (01.57)

*It was closed by five users, not closed by a single mod. If users think.the question should be reopened, they will cast their votes. It doesn't look to be a question of priority. Sorry*

**Revised**: It's now been closed, almost single-handedly, by Journeyman Geek. I suppose the **45 downvotes** made taking that course of action easier. Even though I'm not entirely convinced mods should intervene with *borderline* topic posts unilaterally. I suspect the post would have pretty quickly faded into oblivion by itself.

Normally, in the spirit of solidarity I'd vote to reopen but... it *is* asking for suggestions on something which the majority of community users do not perceive to be a significant issue. If the OP is still keen on wanting the question to be reopened, I'd either modify or get rid of the personally biased, and insulting,  interpretation of the term "teacher", namely

> in which moderators are implied to be smarter and/or more educated than ordinary users and are expected to use pedagogical and/or disciplinary tactics to mold users into better users.

Is there anyone out there  who believes that mods are inherently more intelligent than the common user by virtue of a chat room's name?

Comment: Although I would answer "No" to your final question I have to say it did seem a very strange choice of name. In fact it took me a long while to twig what it was.